# numeric precision is lost after sorting a list using comparator

Tags: java, precision, comparator

I have a method that compares aany given list populated with DMatch objects according to the 'distance' attribute. the problem ia m haveing now is, the distances i get from the sorted list is something like:

```
Debug: MainClass -> descriptorMatcher: Min_Dist: 0.070726834
Debug: MainClass -> descriptorMatcher: Max_Dist: 0.5799786
```

while it should be like:

```
Info: MainClass -> descriptorMatcher: Max_Dist: 0.5799785852432251
Info: MainClass -> descriptorMatcher: Min_Dist: 0.07072683423757553
```

why i am losing numeric precision and how to avoid it.

**Code**:

```
public static List<DMatch> getTopGoodMatches(List<DMatch> list, int startIndx, int range) {
    if (list != null) {
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {

            if (range != 0) {
                if ( (startIndx + range) <= list.size() ){
                    Log.V(TAG, "getTopGoodMatches", range + " match line(s) will be drawn");
                    Collections.sort(list, ascOrder);
                    return list.subList(startIndx, (startIndx + range));
                } else {
                    Log.E(TAG, "getTopGoodMatches", "(startIndx + range) must be <= the total list size");
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                Log.E(TAG, "main", "range can not be zero");
                return null;
            }

        } else {
            Log.E(TAG, "getTopGoodMatches", "the list you passed to this method is empty, empty list can not be sorted.");
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        Log.E(TAG, "getTopGoodMatches", "the list you passed to this method is null, null object can not be sorted.");
        return null;
    }
}

private static Comparator<DMatch> ascOrder = new Comparator<DMatch>() {

    public int compare(DMatch arg0, DMatch arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Double.compare(arg0.distance, arg1.distance);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have arbitrary-precision decimal values you can't use `float` or `double`. Use `BigDecimal` instead. Or convert it to a non decimal value (`int`, `long`) and take care of the number of decimal digits in your logic.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: i dont know why i am not allowed to use BigDecimal? every time i use it eclipse highlight it with red and suggest to convert it float? any idea please

Comment: BigDecimal is a class. So you can't use standard operators to perform operations. So instead of + you have to use .add instead of - .minus and so on. Read the javadoc of BigDecimal

Comment: but as you see in the comparator method posted above i do not have - or +  and when i use BigDecimal.compare.... i receive errors

Comment: If the problem is on the compare method you have to replace "return Double.compare(arg0.distance, arg1.distance);" with "return arg0.distance.compareTo(arg1.distance);"